# How to get the Elapsed time of two cells hh:mm in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

In columns K and L I have time stamps.

Let's say 03:30 is in column K and 04:30 is in column L.

I want the total elapsed amount of time in hh:mm in column P.

I have tried the average function, but it's not coming out correctly.

Comment: What format (the "123" toolbar icon) are the cells set to, and what does "not coming out correctly" mean? If you create a spreadsheet, putt 04:30 and 03:30 in cells A1 and A2, and `=AVERAGE(A1,A2)` in A3, what do you get and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 2):

For times that span past midnight you cannot simply subtract. Or you'll get a negative number.

```
Start 
9:00 PM  

End   
5:38 AM 

Total 
-15:22:00
```

What you'll want to do (where start is column A and End is column B, etc.) is the following formula: `=(B2-A2)+1`

The one being equal to twenty-four hours. So: 9 pm to 5:38 am = 8:38.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean output like this!

Cell C1 shows correct averages.

If yes, set the cell format to 24 hours and use the Average for (Numbers)

[image]

For time Elapsed use simple subtraction = Cell B - Cell A

[image]

Comment: I apologize, I want the elapsed amount of time to show in C1. So the clock starts in A1 and stops in B1. I did format the cells.

Comment: That's not an average, that's simple subtraction.

Comment: Your question says Average. If you want the Elapsed time just subtract.